# How to merge 4 transparent videos so they stack together

Tags: bash, shell, ffmpeg, webm

I have 4 transparent videos with the same size, and the duration is just four seconds. They are all in webm format. I want to combine these 4 webm videos.

I used terminal command:

```
ffmpeg -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i 1.webm -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i 2.webm -filter_complex overlay aa.webm
ffmpeg -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i 3.webm -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i 4.webm -filter_complex overlay bb.webm
ffmpeg -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i aa.webm -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i bb.webm -filter_complex overlay output.webm
```

Is there a solution here that can be solved in one sentence? A simpler solution that would stack these four videos for 4 seconds and maintain transparency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is relatively straightforward:

`ffmpeg -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i 1.webm -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i 2.webm -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i 3.webm -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i 4.webm -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay[aa];[2:v][3:v]overlay[bb];[aa][bb]overlay" -c:v libvpx-vp9 output.webm`

---

- Overlay `1.webm` and `2.webm` to `[aa]` (temporary name).

  ```
   [0:v][1:v]overlay[aa]
  ```
- Overlay `3.webm` and `4.webm` to `[bb]` (temporary name).

  ```
   [2:v][3:v]overlay[bb]
  ```
- Overlay `[aa]` and `[bb]`:

  ```
   [aa][bb]overlay
  ```